# Prolog Path Finding with Prerequisites

Tags: prolog

So I tried to make this program myself, but I'm really stuck on it. The question is as follows:

> Given a task T in the network, a path to T is a list of tasks
>   starting with a task X that has no prerequisites, finishing with T, and
>   such that every element of the list, apart from X, has its predecessor as a
>   prerequisite.
>
> - If a task T has no prerequisites then there is a single path to it given
>     by the list [T].
> - Otherwise the paths to T can be found by calculating a list of all the
>     paths to prerequisites of T and extending these paths with the element
>     T.
> - The list of all paths to tasks in a list Ts can be calculated by starting
>     with the empty list and appending the paths which lead to each
>     successive element.
>
> Define predicates paths and all paths to calculate respectively the paths
>   to a single task and to tasks given in a list, e.g.
>
> ```
> ?- paths(f,Paths).
>
> Paths = [[b, c, f]]
>
> ?- paths(g,Paths).
>
> Paths = [[e, g], [b, c, f, g], [k,h,g]].
> ```
>
> Prerequisites are made like that:
>
> ```
> prereqs(e,[]).
> prereqs(f,[c]).
> prereqs(g,[e,f,h]).
> ```

I tried to define path predicate, but instead of one list I get nested lists.

```
add(X, List, [X|List]).

path(T, [H|Hs]) :-
    prereqs(T, []),
    add(T, [], [H|Hs]).

path(T, [H|Hs]) :-
    prereqs(T, [N|_]),
    add(T,[] , Hs),
    path(N, H).
```

I get these answers when queried:

```
?- path(f, Path).
Path = [[[b], c], f] .

?- path(e, Path).
Path = [e] .
```

At this point, I don't understand how to make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but list syntax seems to confuse you a bit. And, unfortunately, your `add` predicate doesn't help.

Let's try to understand what `add` means in the two cases that you use it. In the first clause of `path`, you have the goal `add(T, [], [H|Hs])`. We can ask Prolog what this means:

```
?- add(T, [], [H|Hs]).
T = H,
Hs = [].
```

So the first clause of `path` can only apply if `Hs` is the empty list (hence `[H|Hs]` is the same as `[H]`) and `T` is the same as `H`. We can therefore rewrite that clause like this:

```
path(T, [T]) :-
    prereqs(T, []).
```

This looks reasonable, and in fact it is the direct translation into Prolog of the relevant part of the specification:

> If a task T has no prerequisites then there is a single path to it given by the list [T].

Now let's try the same for the use of `add` in the second clause of `path`. It takes the following form:

```
?- add(T, [], Hs).
Hs = [T].
```

Simplifying the second clause of `path` as above, using this equation, yields this:

```
path(T, [H, T]) :-
    prereqs(T, [N|_]),
    path(N, H).
```

Note that the second argument in the head is `[H, T]`, since `[H|Hs]` = `[H|[T]]` = `[H, T]`. So this can only succeed for two-element lists, which is what you are seeing. (The first element of each of these lists can be another nested two-element list.)

What you are looking for instead is something more along these lines:

```
path(T, Path) :-
    prereqs(T, [N|_]),
    path(N, PathToPrerequisite),
    append(PathToPrerequisite, [T], Path).
```

This still has a bug in that it will not find all paths, but it can at least already generate those that it did finds in the correct format:

```
?- path(f, Path).
Path = [b, c, f] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I’ll try to do it now so it would show all paths.